# Copy only the structure of vtkImageData to another vtkImageData with filled with zeros

Tags: c++, vtk

I am now building a medical annotating system using c++ with vtk.

I want to draw lines or paint on slices(axial, coronal, sagittal) of 3d vtkimagedata and save the painted image of 3d vtkimagedata consecutively.
So I am planning to make a new empty(filled with zeros) but has identical attribute as original vtkimagedata.

Is there anyone know how to copy only the structure of vtkimagedata to another one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the properties of a `vtkDataSet` object with the [`ShallowCopy()`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSet.html#a05e14c4924a6e5281333856baee5d9be) or [`DeepCopy()`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSet.html#ab9fcb7cee80a2f22bafb261f564258ed) functions but if you are interested only in the geometric structure of a given [`vtkImageData`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html) object, I think that you can do it this way:

```
// copy attributes from a to b (assuming access to a by address)
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> b = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
b->SetOrigin(a->GetOrigin());
b->SetSpacing(a->GetSpacing());
b->SetExtent(a->GetExtent());
```

Then you can add a new field (associated on points in the following example).
Feel free to modify type and name to suit your needs :

```
// allocate memory for a new scalar field
vtkIdType numberOfPoints = b->GetNumberOfPoints();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCharArray> f = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCharArray>::New();
f->SetNumberOfComponents(1);
f->SetNumberOfTuples(numberOfPoints);
f->SetName("NewScalarFieldName");

// fill the array with zeros
char *arr = static_cast<char*>(f->GetVoidPointer(0));
std::fill(arr, arr + numberOfPoints, 0);

// add the field to the data set
b->GetPointData()->AddArray(f);
```

Here, I used `static_cast` in order to have access to the raw data and modify it without too much overhead but you can use the [`SetTuple()`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArray.html#a32eefb4180f5c18455995bb0315bc356) function too.